# Are Kepler's laws proven wrong recently? Or how were they Proven by Johannes Kepler just by observing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

1. The Law of Orbits: All planets move in elliptical orbits, with the sun at one focus.
2. The Law of Areas: A line that connects a planet to the sun sweeps out equal areas in equal times.
3. The Law of Periods: The square of the period of any planet is proportional to the cube of the semimajor axis of its orbit.

Kepler's laws were derived for orbits around the sun, but they apply to satellite orbits as well.

Comment: What makes you think they were proven wrong recently?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was initially written with observations, but Newton's Law of Gravitation were able to derive them from scratch.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Precession_of_elliptical_orbits) for what you appear to be asking about (viz. mmesser314's answer), & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Formulary) for @KshitjjKumar's point.

Comment: Move to [History of Science & Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

They were proven very slightly wrong in the 19th century. The crucial discrepancy was discovered by Le Verrier in 1859. You can read about it in [EMPIRICAL FOUNDATIONS OF THE RELATIVISTIC GRAVITY](https://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/0504/0504116.pdf). It was a mystery for decades, until Einstein explained it with his theory of General Relativity.

Well before Le Verrier, the orbits of the planets are seen to be almost but not quite elliptical. Kepler's laws and Newtonian gravity both predict that if the Sun had just one planet, the orbit would be elliptical. But as is, the planets attract each other. While this gravitational pull is much less than the Sun's, it is enough to distort the orbits measurably.

People calculated how big the distortion should be and corrected for it. Uranus was still not elliptical. The pattern of the distortion matched the pull of an unknown planet. This led to the discovery of Neptune. So the laws were vindicated.

Mercury also had unexplainable perturbations. Le Verrier found that after all known disturbances were removed, the orbit was almost an ellipse, but not quite. It was an ellipse whose orientation changed very slowly. The major axis rotated $43$ arc seconds $(0.012^o)$ per century. Tiny, but measurable. See [How could the precession of Mercury be known so accurately in the 19th century?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323977/37364)

In 1915, Einstein published his theory of General Relativity. General Relativity predicted the $46$ arc second per century precession of Mercury's perihelion, while Newton and Kepler did not.

Subsequently, many experimental tests have shown that the laws of Newton and Kepler are extremely good approximations to weak gravity, they are not perfect. The differences become more important in strong gravity, where strong means something like $10^{11}$ g - the gravity of a neutron star or black hole.

Comment: They were proved wrong in the late 17th century with the publication of Newton's *Principia*.  The Newtonian precession of Mercury's orbit due to perturbations by the other planets is over ten times greater than is its relativistic precession.

Comment: @DavidHammen - I understand your point, but I wasn't counting an orbit perturbed by other planets as a violation. After Newton, Kepler's law was recognized as a consequence of Newton's law, and therefore deviations are to be expected in a system with more than one planet.

Comment: Well thank you.